# Can a settler be assigned a bed AND a job or does it need to either or?

Tags: fallout-4

I have plenty of beds but my settlers are unhappy but they also just sleep where ever. Plus some of my NPC's just quit their job and the item is unassigned, why is this? But my main question is: Can I assign a settler to a job and a bed or if I assign a settler to a bed will that leave the job open?

Comment: You could probably break off the "quitting jobs" question, into it's own separate question.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your main question:
They can (and should) be assigned to both. Assigning a settler to a bed should not make them quit their job (and assigning them a job should not unassign their bed).

Settlers won't like not having a bed specifically assigned to them, but it largely won't impact how your settlement functions (although you'll get complaints of course, and it likely has a slight impact on happiness). But your focus should first be on assigning jobs (if you have any remaining, which you may not), as they will have a more direct impact on your settlement.

Answer (score 3):

All settlers need a bed, and will be unhappy if there aren't enough beds for everyone in a settlement. That is true whether they are also assigned to a job or not.

Settlers can *optionally* be assigned to a "job" by assigning them to a food resource, guard tower, scavenger station or store. They can only be assigned to one such job (although if assigned to food production they can be responsible for up to 6 food units, e.g. 6 tato plants and 3 mutfruit plants).

If they aren't assigned to a job they will scavenge, which just means that random junk items (and in my case **loads** of flare gun ammo) will appear in your workshop. Building a scavenging station and assigning someone to it will make them scavenge more efficiently.

Comment: I was wondering where all those Flares were coming from.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of unassigned settlers scavenging on their own. Any other references for that?

Comment: @DCShannon, page 244 in the official strategy guide from Prima. "People without assigned tasks automatically generate salvage, so a large, happy population can provide a steady stream of building materials."

Comment: @boomstick Alright. +1. I don't trust those Prima guides as far as I can throw them, but I'll watch out for that.

Comment: I haven't confirmed it definitely happening myself, because I have scavenging stations at most settlements, and it's hard to notice a bit more junk turning up if you already have junk in the workshop. I don't catalogue all my junk :)